# Is there a open source implementation for Fellegi-Sunter?

Tags: java, search, record-linkage

Is there a open source implementation for Fellegi-Sunter?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? [Wikipedia: Record Linkage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage)

Check under "Software implementations" for possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the thing I need. Now I'm seeking for  reference: who and where did try to deploy listed products.

Comment: [Splink](https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/splink) Provides an open source implementation of Fellegi Sunter, which is used in [uk government](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/joined-up-data-in-government-the-future-of-data-linking-methods/splink-mojs-open-source-library-for-probabilistic-record-linkage-at-scale).  [More info about the specific flavour of the mathematical model here](https://www.robinlinacre.com/maths_of_fellegi_sunter/)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some open source implementations:

- http://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe (author of this)
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/febrl/
- https://github.com/larsga/Duke