# Deduplication with scoring framework/application/server on Java to work with database input staging

Tags: java, database, duplicates, record-linkage

Please suggest me Java product (I would prefer open-source) which does do:

1. data deduplication
2. deduplication scoring
3. allows to customize deduplication rules and scoring rules.

Please see the example:

1. I have an input staging database named "INPUT_DB"
2. I have a table named "INPUT_PERSONS"
3. There are several fields in this table:

   ID (some meaningless surrogate primary key)
   FIRST_NAME
   LAST_NAME
   SECOND_NAME
   BIRTH_DATE
   PASSPORT_SERIES (PASSPORT_SERIES + PASSPORT_NUM is a unique identifier of a citizen)
   PASSPORT_NUM

I have to look through all records in INPUT_PERSONS and find duplicates and matches.
Several rules should be created:

1. if PASSPORT_SERIES+PASSPORT_NUM equals to some record it means these two records are duplicates. The score for such situation is 100 out of 100
2. If FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME are equal, but PASSPORT_SERIES+PASSPORT_NUM has one different character (misprint for example), then these records are possible duplicates and their score is 90 out of 100.
3. And so on....

Is it possible to find some ready solution and use it as a base?

Answer (score 1):

Ive done this in the past and based it on the fellEgi-sunter algo. See this question: [Is there a open source implementation for Fellegi-Sunter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152217/is-there-a-open-source-implementation-for-fellegi-sunter)

Answer (score 0):

The DUKE project may fill your requirement: https://github.com/larsga/Duke